# How to use an exit selection on text with tspan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a Pie Chart which updates as you move the slider, the chart also has labels which I want to update and reposition as the data changes. When I update the chart new labels are drawn but the old labels are not removed. I have managed to get the Join/Enter/Update/Remove sequence working on the chart itself but not the labels.

Is there anything different about text that means this update sequence does not work?

```
function update() {
// Scales
    const colors = d3.quantize(d3.interpolateSpectral, dataset.length);
    const colorScale = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(dataset.map((d) => d.type))
      .range(colors);
//Define Pie Chart
    const generationPie = d3
      .pie()
      .padAngle(0.005)
      .value((d) => d.generation)
      .sort(null);
//Pass dataset into Pie Chart
    const slices = generationPie(dataset);
//JOIN DATA
    const arcs = arcGroup.selectAll("path").data(slices);
//ENTER NEW DATA
    arcs
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.data.type))
      .each(function (d) {
        this._current = d;
      });
//UPDATE
    arcs.transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", arcTween);
//REMOVE OLD DATA
    arcs.exit().remove();

    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function (t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }
//==============================================================

//Data timestamp
//Join
    const dataTimeLabel = dataTimestamp.text(timeFormat(dataTime));
//Update
    dataTimeLabel.transition().duration(1000);
//ENTER
    dataTimeLabel.enter().text(timeFormat(dataTime));
//REMOVE
    dataTimestamp.exit().remove();

//==============================================================
//Labels
    const labelsGroup = ctr
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.ctrHeight / 2}, ${dimensions.ctrWidth / 2})`
    );
//JOIN
    const labelArcs = labelsGroup.selectAll("text").data(slices);
//ENTER
    labelArcs
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${arcLabels.centroid(d)})`)
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .attr("x", "-2em")
      .text((d) => d.data.type)
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("x", "-2.3em")
      .attr("y", "+1.2em")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
      .attr("font-size", 12)
      .text((d) => commaFormat(d.data.percentage).toLocaleString() + " %")
//UPDATE
    labelArcs.transition().duration(1000)
//REMOVE
    labelArcs.exit().remove();
  }
```

Any help would be really welcome.

Comment: It seems the reason is you are always creating a new g element with labelsGroup so the selection.exit() is always empty. Take a look at the elements with the inspector

Comment: @ee2Dev yes you are right about this, though I cannot work out how to do it differently?

Comment: append your "g" element where you build your initial svg not in the update function

Comment: @ee2Dev this stops the issue where it was creating lots of new labels, but now it does not generate any new labels other than the initial data and they persist as the data changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of the [comment about re-appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725136/how-to-use-an-exit-selection-on-text-with-tspan#comment117955428_66725136) the groups and the [answer about splitting the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728885/5768908), you have to change the text position in your update selection...

```
labelArcs.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${arcLabels.centroid(d)})`);
```

...as well as changing the text values in the `<tspan>` elements:

```
labelArcs.select(".type")
    .text((d) => d.data.type);

labelArcs.select(".value")
    .text((d) => commaFormat(d.data.percentage).toLocaleString() + " %");
```

Here is the resulting code:

```js
async function draw() {
  // Data
  let dataset;
  let dataTime;
  const commaFormat = d3.format(",");
  const timeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M");

  // Dimensions
  let dimensions = {
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    margins: 10,
  };

  dimensions.ctrWidth = dimensions.width - dimensions.margins * 2;
  dimensions.ctrHeight = dimensions.height - dimensions.margins * 2;
  const radius = dimensions.ctrHeight / 3;

  // Draw Image
  const svg = d3
    .select("#chart-area")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimensions.width)
    .attr("height", dimensions.height);

  const ctr = svg
    .append("g") // <g>
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.margins}, ${dimensions.margins})`
    );

  const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.8);

  const arcLabels = d3
    .arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 1.2)
    .innerRadius(radius * 1.2);

  const arcGroup = ctr
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.ctrHeight / 2}, ${dimensions.ctrWidth / 2})`
    );

  const dataTimestamp = svg
    .append("text")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.ctrHeight / 2}, ${dimensions.ctrWidth / 2})`
    )
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("x", "+0.2em")
    .attr("y", "+2.5em")
    .attr("font-size", 20);

  //Labels
  const labelsGroup = ctr
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.ctrHeight / 2}, ${dimensions.ctrWidth / 2})`
    );

  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/1crisl/test/main/data.json").then((data) => {
    const timeArray = data.map((record) => {
      return record.unixTime;
    });
    const minTime = d3.min(timeArray);
    const maxTime = d3.max(timeArray);
    let i = timeArray.length - 1;
    $("#dateLabel1").text(timeFormat(minTime));
    $("#dateLabel2").text(timeFormat(maxTime));
    $("#date-slider").slider({
      max: timeArray.length - 1,
      min: 0,
      value: timeArray.length - 1,
      change: (event, ui) => {
        i = $("#date-slider").slider("value");
        dataTime = data[i].unixTime;
        dataset = data[i].data.filter(function(obj) {
          return obj.percentage > "1";
        });
        update();
      },
    });
    dataTime = data[i].unixTime;
    dataset = data[i].data.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.percentage > "1";
    });
    update();
  });

  function update() {
    // Scales
    const colors = d3.quantize(d3.interpolateSpectral, dataset.length); //Generates a colour for each item in the dataset array
    const colorScale = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(dataset.map((d) => d.type))
      .range(colors);
    //Define Pie Chart
    const generationPie = d3
      .pie()
      .padAngle(0.005)
      .value((d) => d.generation)
      .sort(null);
    //Pass dataset into Pie Chart
    const slices = generationPie(dataset);
    //JOIN DATA
    const arcs = arcGroup.selectAll("path").data(slices);
    //ENTER NEW DATA
    arcs
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.data.type))
      .each(function(d) {
        this._current = d;
      });
    //UPDATE
    arcs.transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", arcTween);
    //REMOVE OLD DATA
    arcs.exit().remove();

    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }
    //==============================================================

    //Data timestamp
    //Join
    const dataTimeLabel = dataTimestamp.text(timeFormat(dataTime));
    //Update
    dataTimeLabel.transition().duration(1000);
    //ENTER
    dataTimeLabel.enter().text(timeFormat(dataTime));
    //REMOVE
    dataTimeLabel.exit().remove();

    //==============================================================

    //JOIN
    const labelArcs = labelsGroup.selectAll("text").data(slices, d => d.data.type);
    //ENTER
    const textGroup = labelArcs
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${arcLabels.centroid(d)})`);

    textGroup
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .attr("x", "-2em")
      .attr("class", "type")
      .text((d) => d.data.type);

    textGroup
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("x", "-2.3em")
      .attr("y", "+1.2em")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
      .attr("font-size", 12)
      .attr("class", "value")
      .text((d) => commaFormat(d.data.percentage).toLocaleString() + " %");

    //UPDATE
    labelArcs.select(".type")
      .text((d) => d.data.type);

    labelArcs.select(".value")
      .text((d) => commaFormat(d.data.percentage).toLocaleString() + " %");

    labelArcs.transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${arcLabels.centroid(d)})`);


    //REMOVE
    labelArcs.exit().remove();
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Visualisation</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQueryUI styling -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Bootstrap grid setup -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="chart-area"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="slider-div">
          <label>Data Extent</label>
          <br>
          <label><span id="dateLabel1">01/01/2000</span> to <span id="dateLabel2">18/03/2021</span></label>
          <div id="date-slider"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- External JS libraries -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: your percentages are way off.

Comment: Great! Which code didymium build upon? In the question I just see the Update function not the remaining code...

Comment: @ee2Dev I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, I'm just using the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku3v0pn2/9/) OP mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725136/how-to-use-an-exit-selection-on-text-with-tspan/66739494?noredirect=1#comment117968749_66728885).

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn’t see the comment and the jsfiddle since it was not in the question...I was wondering since you post so many great answers and was surprised seeing the remaining code :)

Comment: This worked. Percentages are way off so that I could see the animations more clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to split code:

```
const textGroup = labelArcs
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${arcLabels.centroid(d)})`)
      
textGroup.append("tspan")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .attr("x", "-2em")
      .text((d) => d.data.type)
      
textGroup.append("tspan")
      .attr("x", "-2.3em")
      .attr("y", "+1.2em")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
      .attr("font-size", 12)
      .text((d) => commaFormat(d.data.percentage).toLocaleString() + " %")
```

If it does not help, please provide a snippet of a fiddle to work with

Comment: I've made this change and followed ee2Dev's advice. I have added the code to a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ku3v0pn2/9/